# Printing all occurence of certain document elements of a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I was scraping this particular webpage https://www.zomato.com/srijata , for all the "restaurant reviews"(not the self comments on her own reviews) posted by user "Sri".

```
zomato_ind = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.zomato.com/srijata')
zomato_info = zomato_ind.read()
open('zomato_info.html', 'w').write(zomato_info)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('zomato_info.html'))
soup.find('div','mtop0 rev-text').text
```

This prints her first restaurant review i.e. - "Sri reviewed Big Straw - Chew On This" as :-

```
 u'Rated&nbsp;&nbsp;This is situated right in the heart of the city. The items on the menu are alright and I really had to compromise for bubble tea. The tapioca was not fresh. But the latte and the soda pop my friends tried was good. Another issue which I faced was mosquitos... They almost had me.. Lol..'
```

I also tried another selector :-

I have this questions :-

How can I print the next restaurant review ?  I tried findNextSiblings etc and all but none seem to work.

Comment: Why are saving the html in a file and then reading the file into a soup object?

Comment: That I did as a measure to avoid continuously hitting on the website and thus following security measures against scraping if any !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to write the output to the file, pass the result of `urlopen()` call to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor.

To get the reviews, you need to iterate over all `div` tags with class `rev-text`, and get the [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) of the `div` element inside:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.zomato.com/srijata'))
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='rev-text'):
    print div.div.next_sibling
```

Prints:

```
This is situated right in the heart of the city. The items on the menu are alright and I really had to compromise for bubble tea. The tapioca was not fresh. But the latte and the soda pop my friends tried was good. Another issue which I faced was mosquitos... They almost had me.. Lol..

The ambience is good. The food quality is good. I Didn't find anything to complain. I wanted to visit the place fir a very long time and had dinner today. The meals are very good and if u want the better quality compared to other Andhra restaurants then this is the place. It's far better than nandhana. The staffs are very polite too. 

...
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe that works, but Im still trying to figure out how ? Like why did u use only "rev-text" and not "mtop0 rev-text" ?

Comment: @shalini I've used browser developer tools, inspected several reviews and found that they all follow that `rev-text` class pattern. Well, there are enormous amount of ways to find the reviews on the page, definitely. You are free to choose whatever works for you and whatever you think is reliable. Thank you.

Comment: Alex the issue is that in dev tools class="mtop0 rev-text". So if in your code I replace "rev-text" with "mtop0 rev-text" its not printing anything at all. According to dev tool "mtop0 rev-text" should also work,,,,?

Comment: @shalini hm, where have you found `mtop0` class? I can see it is used but not for reviews - it is used for the current foodie and suggested foodies only..

Answer (score 0):

You should make a for loop and use find_all instead of find:

```
zomato_ind = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.zomato.com/srijata')
zomato_info = zomato_ind.read()
open('zomato_info.html', 'w').write(zomato_info)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('zomato_info.html'))
for div in soup.find_all('div','rev-text'):
    print div.text
```

Also one question: Why are saving the html in a file and then reading the file into a soup object?

Comment: Doesnt work, print div.text ==> AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: sorry try this. I forgot to change find into find_all

Comment: That stops after printing the first review only.